# Pending form response warning after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm submitting data to a Google sheet via an embedded form. I'm using the hidden iframe approach to hijack the default Google redirection to the confirmation page. Form submits fine, but when I go to leave the page I get a 'Pending form response' warning popup. I'm not submitting via ajax, it's a standard form submission and I thought once the onsubmit function was called the form response would no longer be pending?

Any ideas how to prevent this?

EDIT: added code. The formSubmitted() function hides the form and displays an inline alert.

```
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted) {window.location='#'; formSubmitted();}"></iframe>
<form role="form" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/my-form-guid/formResponse" method="POST" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when modifying the content of my inputs that I was submitting to the form via the iframe.

More specifically, I had the following:

```
$("#feedback-form").on('submit', function() {
    // Do some processing...

    // Show the user a message their form submitted and clear the inputs so they can submit again.
    $("#form-submitted").removeClass("hidden");
    $("input[name='entry.452983228'").val("");
    $("input[name='entry.455283748'").val("");
    $("input[name='entry.462384982'").val("");  
});
```

My clearing of the inputs in the above code was the issue, I assume because I was clearing the inputs before the submit finished processing (and I had a required field in my Google Form).

In summary, maybe check if you're doing something to the form inputs before it's done being submitted.